# calculation on particular subset of rows with group by pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample data set:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {
 'unit': ['UD', 'UD', 'UD', 'UD', 'UD','UD','UC','UC', 'UC', 'UC','UC','UC'],
 'N-D': [ 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4','Q5','Q6','Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4','Q5','Q6'],
 'casenumber': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8,9,10,11],
 'DaysV' : [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,18,19,20,21]

}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.reindex_axis(['unit','N-D','casenumber','DaysV'], axis=1)  #rearranging column order
```

it looks like this, I have made the numbers simple for illustration purposes:

```
  unit N-D  casenumber  DaysV
   UD  Q1           1     14
   UD  Q2           2     15
   UD  Q3           3     16
   UD  Q4           4     17
   UD  Q5           5     18
   UD  Q6           6     19
   UC  Q1           7     20
   UC  Q2           8     21
   UC  Q3           9     22
   UC  Q4          10     23
   UC  Q5          11     24
   UC  Q6          12     25
```

I want to have 2 new rows for sum(casenumber) and sum(DaysV) for 'N-D' for each 'unit' but skip Q3. 
desire output:

```
  unit N-D  casenumber  DaysV
   UD  Q1           1     14
   UD  Q2           2     15
   UD  Q3           3     16
   UD  Q4           4     17
   UD  Q5           5     18
   UD  Q6           6     19
   UD SUM(Q1,Q2)    3     29
   UD SUM(Q4,Q5,Q6) 15    54
   UC  Q1           7     20
   UC  Q2           8     21
   UC  Q3           9     22
   UC  Q4           10    23
   UC  Q5           11    24
   UC  Q6           12    25
   UC SUM(Q1,Q2)    15    41
   UC SUM(Q4,Q5,Q6) 33    72
```

Comment: Are your N-D values consistent or do they change? Would it be acceptable to hard code group 1,2 and group 4,5,6?

Comment: yeah they change, there are actually more rows involved than the sample dataset I'm showing here.

Comment: Okay, is the a way to determine which values to drop like Q3 or is that hard coded?

Comment: yeah it will just be called 'Q3' , the name is different in the actual data but it will always be the same. this part i think needs to be hard coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {
 'unit': ['UD', 'UD', 'UD', 'UD', 'UD','UC', 'UC', 'UC','UC','UC'],
 'N-D': [ 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4','Q5','Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4','Q5'],
 'casenumber': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8,9,10],
 'DaysV' : [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,18,19,20]

}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.reindex_axis(['unit','N-D','casenumber','DaysV'], axis=1) 

df = df.assign(group=np.where(df['N-D'].isin(['Q1','Q2']),'Sum(Q1,Q2)',np.where(df['N-D'].isin(['Q4','Q5']),'Sum(Q4,Q5)',np.nan)))

df_out = pd.concat([df.drop('group',axis=1),
          df.groupby(['unit','group']).sum().reset_index().query('group != "nan"').rename(columns={'group':'N-D'})])
```

Output:

```
  unit         N-D  casenumber  DaysV
0   UD          Q1           1     11
1   UD          Q2           2     12
2   UD          Q3           3     13
3   UD          Q4           4     14
4   UD          Q5           5     15
5   UC          Q1           6     16
6   UC          Q2           7     17
7   UC          Q3           8     18
8   UC          Q4           9     19
9   UC          Q5          10     20
0   UC  Sum(Q1,Q2)          13     33
1   UC  Sum(Q4,Q5)          19     39
3   UD  Sum(Q1,Q2)           3     23
4   UD  Sum(Q4,Q5)           9     29
```

## EDIT added sorting

```
df_out.sort_values(by=['unit','N-D'])
```

Output:

```
  unit         N-D  casenumber  DaysV
5   UC          Q1           6     16
6   UC          Q2           7     17
7   UC          Q3           8     18
8   UC          Q4           9     19
9   UC          Q5          10     20
0   UC  Sum(Q1,Q2)          13     33
1   UC  Sum(Q4,Q5)          19     39
0   UD          Q1           1     11
1   UD          Q2           2     12
2   UD          Q3           3     13
3   UD          Q4           4     14
4   UD          Q5           5     15
3   UD  Sum(Q1,Q2)           3     23
4   UD  Sum(Q4,Q5)           9     29
```

Comment: This was the solution to your original question before add Q6, you can modify that df.assign to handle the different groups.